# What are the advantages of TLongArrayList over long[]

Tags: java, arrays, trove4j

I saw that in some places that the data structure TLongArrayList is used instead of an array of long primitives. I wish to ask what is the benefit to use TLongArrayList over long[] ?

Comment: There is no `TLongArrayList` class in the standard class library. Where did you see this class?

Comment: gnu.trove.list.array.TLongArrayList

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `TLongArrayList` class from the [GNU Trove](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/html/overview.html) project implements a [dynamic array data structure (wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array) for elements that are primitive `long` values.

The benefit of "dynamic array" over the native fixed-sized `long[]` array is that you can add and remove elements, including in the middle, and that the data structure automatically expands to meet usage. In comparison, when you create an array you have to decide the size at the time of creation, and all the array elements are created at that time. With a fixed sized array, you cannot add or remove elements, only replace existing elements.

Answer (score 1):

Versatility and usability of an ArrayList while using primitive longs to store the actual values.

Comment: What I understand from your answer is that TLongArrayList has all the methods ArrayList has, but it stores only primitive values (instead of Long objects) and therefore is more memory efficient.

Comment: indeed, the other answer explains it in more detail.